# Place subcaptions next to subfigures

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, captions

I am trying to place the subcaptions of my subfigures to left of each image. To illustrate this, I have included an image of the desired result and the corresponding MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.55\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}
   \caption{}
   \label{fig:Ng1} 
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.55\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-b}
   \caption{}
   \label{fig:Ng2}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Here is my main caption. (a) is a subcaption. (b) is a subcaption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Problem solved?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I define a `varsubfigure` environment where the number is typeset centered with respect to the contents of the environment. Beware that the label is in a zero width box.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{xparse} % uncomment if using LaTeX released prior to 2020-10-01

\NewDocumentEnvironment{varsubfigure}{O{c}mo}
 {% #1 = optional positioning argument, #2 = width, #3 = label
  \begin{subfigure}[#1]{#2}
    \if#1t\vspace{0pt}\fi
    \makebox[0pt][r]{%
      \refstepcounter{subfigure}%
      \IfValueT{#3}{\label{#3}}%
      (\thesubfigure) % <--- a space here
    }%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
 }
 {\end{tabular}\if#1b\vspace{0pt}\fi\end{subfigure}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{varsubfigure}{0.55\textwidth}[fig:Ng1]
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{varsubfigure}

\begin{varsubfigure}{0.55\textwidth}[fig:Ng2]
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{varsubfigure}

\caption{Here is my main caption. (a) is a subcaption. (b) is a subcaption.}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{varsubfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}[fig:Ng1-2]
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{varsubfigure}\hfil
\begin{varsubfigure}[b]{0.20\textwidth}[fig:Ng2-2]
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{varsubfigure}

\caption{Here is my main caption. (a) is a subcaption. (b) is a subcaption.}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \parbox[b]{0.30\textwidth}{\subcaption{First sub with more text. More text. First sub with more text.}} \quad \parbox[b]{0.65\textwidth}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}}
        \\[.5cm]
        \parbox[b]{0.30\textwidth}{\subcaption{Second sub}} \quad\parbox[b]{0.65\textwidth}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}}
        \\[.5cm]
        \parbox[b]{0.30\textwidth}{\subcaption{Third sub}} \quad  \parbox[b]{0.65\textwidth}{\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image}}
        \caption{The main figure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You have this result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun.  Note, you cannot make the image `\linewidth` wide and leave room for the subcaption.  Nor do you know how big the subcaption will be in general.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\sidecaption}[2][\empty]% #1=caption, #2=image
{\bgroup% use local registers
  \sbox0{#2}% measure image
  \rotatebox[origin=Bl]{90}{\parbox{\ht0}{\subcaption[position=above]{#1}}}%
  \usebox0
\egroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\sidecaption[Some text here\label{fig:Ng1}]{\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image-a}}

\sidecaption[\label{fig:Ng2}]{\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image-b}}

\caption{Here is my main caption. (a) is a subcaption. (b) is a subcaption.}
\end{figure}

\ref{fig:Ng1} and \ref{fig:Ng2}.
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]